# Multiple GUI Kits in a single Python app

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, cross-platform

I'm a Python newbie but I'm interested in going into the depths of the language. I learned recently how to make simple GUI apps with wxPython and I loved it, I've read around that is the best cross-platform GUI kit around - yet, there are better "native" GUI kits (pyGTK, IronPython (if I'm not mistaken), pyObjc, etc.), but they are individual.

Is there a way I can "mix" those GUI libraries into a single app? How can I provide the best GUI experience in a cross-platform app?

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: "How can I provide the best GUI experience in a cross-platform app?" Mixing a bunch of different GUI libraries together in one application certainly *won't* give the best GUI experience. Pick the library you think is best and use it consistently. As to which is best, that's a subjective question. You'll have to try a few and decide for yourself which you think is the best.

Comment: @MarkByers What I meant is that if I was gonna write a cross-platform app, I should use pyGTK for Linux, PyWin32 for Windows and such **in the same app** - I didn't know if it was possible or not, hence the question. I even thought that I had to code a different app for each platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grate benefit from wxPython is its use of native widgets where possible, so on GTK platform it'll use GTK, on windows it will use win32, and on mac it will use cocoa/carbon.

If you **don't** write a cross-platform app, then you should better use the specific API to this platform, e.g. pyGTK (Gnome etc.), PyWin32T (Windows) or whatever native toolkit on your platform, as it is normally more updated to the latest API than wxPython.

Comment: "...as it is normally more updated to the latest API than wxPython" - this is really useful to know. I didn't know that wxPython used native Cocoa, so that's a big plus, and because the cross-compatibility is important to me, I should stick to that. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: The dev branch already has cocoa support, but it will be imported into stable branch only when 3.0 comes out (they aim for winter 2013). That means on Mac you'll have to either use dev version or 32-bit version. See the wxpython download page for more info.

Comment: The dev version is just fine for production purposes. The naming scheme behind wxWidgets needs to be changed as it is causing a lot of confusion lately.

Comment: I know, and you know, but the poor end-user guy doesn't know that he has to download a development release. Also, it isn't available as a .deb :/  
And yes, I agree they should just release 3.0 instead of 2.9.5 and just switch to a normal version numbering :)